# Truncation using round function isn't achieved as expected in sql server

Tags: sql, ssis-2012, msbi

I have a field stored in float datatype. I need to convert it to numeric without it getting implicitly rounded in the process of conversion.

I have tried round(float_data,scale,1). Seems to work fine for most of the cases.but when the number of digits after decimal places is less than scale mentioned in round function it tries to floor down the number rather than appending 0 at the end.

For instance, round (0.0243,5,1) returns 0.02429. Why isn't it simply truncating the number to the number of digits mentioned?

I know this issue is when we use float as source datatype but I cannot change the source datatype.

The same truncation happens right when the same is achieved via ssis. Is there any way in sql to achieve this?

Comment: Cast to decimal datatype.

Comment: I would want to avoid rounding when casting... I cannot simply cast to decimal without achieving truncation perfectly

Comment: You mean you really want not rounding, but truncating? Cast to decimal with one more digit and truncate last one then. Floating point math is full of surprises :)

Answer (score 1):

Because when converted to a float, the decimal 0.0243 is stored as 0.02429999969899654388427734375, which truncates to 0.02429.  Looks like you want to round instead of truncate, eg

```
declare @f float = 0.0243
select round(@f,5,0)
```

Comment: Hi David, 0.0243 is just a  number from the database stored in float datatype. Used it as an example for explanatory purpose. I have thousands of numbers stored. Round function works perfectly fine for truncation when the number stored has digits after decimal places  greater than the scale mentioned in round. For instance if the number from database was 0.02429999...834- using round I would get round(0.0242999,5,1) as 0.02429 which is ok for me . When the number from db is 0.0243 and this is applied to round I'm getting 0.02429, I'd expect 0.02430  any lead to achieve this would be helpful

Comment: But 0.0243 simply _isn't_ a valid float.  The closest float is 0.02429999969899654388427734375, which is what you actually are storing.